# Bootstrapping from a fork of a repository

Tags: git, github

I intend to bootstrap my own project from an available open source project. Ideally I would have forked it and renamed the repository but the source repository consists of two folders.

One for the client app and one for the server app.

I intend to keep the two as seperate repos so what are my options?

cloning locally and uploading to a new repo feels slightly unethical to me. I would mention the source repo in the readme in this case.

I do not intend to bring over any new changes most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I intend to keep the two as seperate repos so what are my options?

Clone two times (just copy the 1st local clone to a different directory). In the 1st clone remove server subdirectory, in the 2nd remove client.

> cloning locally and uploading to a new repo feels slightly unethical to me.

Shouldn't be a problem if the license allows it.

> I would mention the source repo in the readme in this case.

That's enough, I'm sure.